# How can I debug a Java Google App Engine app in IDEA while using the GAE Maven plugin?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea

I have set up my pom.xml [like so](https://github.com/sanity/LastCalc/blob/master/pom.xml), and it appears to be working for the most part, I can start the devserver and update the application.

My problem is that I can't seem to debug the devserver.  I tried launching the devserver maven goal in debug mode from within IDEA, but when I set breakpoints they are ignored.

I found in the GAE Maven plugin docs that you can launch the devserver in debug mode with the following configuration:

```
<jvmFlags>
  <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
  <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
</jvmFlags>
```

However I don't know how to tell IDEA to connect the debugger when I start the Maven Run/Debug configuration.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The configuration mentioned in your question looks good. So, you have:

```xml
<jvmFlags>
  <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
  <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
</jvmFlags>
```

1. When you run your Maven build

   ```
   mvn appengine:devserver
   ```

   at some point it halts and waits for the remote debugger to connect.
2. In IDEA, go to `Run > Edit Configurations...` and add a new **Remote** configuration.
3. Give it a name and check parameters (especially the port).[image]
4. Click OK
5. Run the debugger with `Run > Debug '<name of your config>'` (`Shift-F9`)

Comment: Oh, it's not particularly important, but are you aware of a way to consolidate both run configs into a single run config?

Comment: You can also add the goals appengine:deserver_stop & appengine:devserver_start before attaching the debugger. This will automatically run the server and you'll be able to debug.