# How to setup IntelliJ Java App Engine project to use Services (Modules)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I've been using IntelliJ successfully for quite a while to develop App Engine projects that contain a single service (formerly 'module'), but am having difficulty setting up a project up that contains more than one service (a default front-end service plus one or more backend services).

I understand the multi-module EAR deployment folder structure, which is different from the single WAR structure, but I have not been able to figure out how to successfully launch the development server with this configuration to debug before I deploy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it in the meantime? I'm stumped.

Comment: Nope. And it's been a long time and no comments other than yours. Unexpected.

Comment: JB are a bit behind on the GAE multi-module stuff. On PyCharm I was able to setup a run config to work with the modules, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29839511/4495081. Check your devserver's options, maybe you can do the same for the java side. Couldn't fix deployment, as its options are not configurable, so still deploying manually.

Comment: just to get sure:  you want to debug the code of one of your modules, right?

Comment: I certainly do.

Comment: Are you using Gradle Build or the Intellij App Engine Plugin for your project?

Comment: I'm using the Intellij App Engine Plugin, but I could use Gradle Build if that would help.

Comment: I would prefer with the IntelliJ App Engine plugin because that's what I currently use. I guess I should try out Gradle at some point but that's too many changes at once.

Comment: I have a running multi module ear project with Gradle which I can debug on my local development server. But when you prefer the plugin, I cant help you

Comment: Can you help with Gradle setup?

Comment: please see my answer below. Just tell me when you need some more infos. I were able to setup my environment with those examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My application is structured as a multi module Gradle project. I have a top level Gradle Build file and
three subprojects. One project contains the EAR project, and two projects are Goolge App Engine War projects.

I would propose that you start with trying to setup such a project. You will find a good example with a corresponding
project structure at Googles Github

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

You will deploy the ear to your locale dev server by running the ear gradle task appengineRun

You need to add the following entry to your ear gradle build file (keep the other entries)

```
appengine {

    jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000']

}
```

Next step is to configure a Remote Debug configuration similar to this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692212/2062634

After you started your application you have to start your remote debug configuration which will attach the debugger.

Comment: Thanks so much. Finally, this is possible for me.