# Run Multi Module Java App Engine (EAR) application on Eclipse App Engine Standard on localhost on debug

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, ear

My Project looks a lot like this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

Wanted to be able to run it on a eclipse local server on debug mode but does not look like Eclipse App Engine Standard on localhost accepts ears. it says they are not supported. What can I do?

Also I added the war projects individually to the local server but getting:

HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

Powered by Jetty://

If I use maven I can build and deploy from the command line, but does not help much since cannot use the eclipse debugger.

Comment: maybe this two links will help your https://blog.knoldus.com/2010/06/24/remote-debugging-google-app-engine-application-on-eclipse/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112458/how-to-setup-intellij-java-app-engine-project-to-use-services-modules/42411116#42411116

Comment: At high level seems good. So can you step through with the debugger just like you would normally do in eclipse?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer do you work at Spectrum

Comment: it works like you are used the debugger in eclipse. What is Spectrum?

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelMeyer had you confused from someone else (its a hospital).

Comment: @MichaelMeyer It worked, i love it how it stops in the middle of the deploy and waits for the remote to bind the port. Could you post an answer and ill mark it correct.

Comment: @MichaelMeyer also having one more problem. Cannot see the ear project on the Remote Java Application - Debug Configuration but i can see the wars. The first war binds fine even though the jvm flags are set on the ear pom. I suspect I'm missing some property on the ear project but this happens for the google project above too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this two links will help you

https://blog.knoldus.com/2010/06/24/remote-debugging-google-app-engine-application-on-eclipse/

[How to setup IntelliJ Java App Engine project to use Services (Modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112458/how-to-setup-intellij-java-app-engine-project-to-use-services-modules/42411116#42411116)

This links will show you how to enable remote debugging for eclipse and how to setup remote debugging for a Multi Modulue Google App Engine Project with Intellij (without the Google App Engine Plugin) and Gradle

Regards

Michael